# i3 assign spotify to workspace

Tags: xorg, i3

I'm trying to assign Spotify to a specific workspace but with no luck.

My i3 config file looks like this

```
#Startup-programs 
exec firefox 
exec spotify

assign [class="Spotify"] $ws4   
assign [class="Firefox"] $ws2
```

`xprop` on Spotify gives me this output

```
_NET_WM_ICON(CARDINAL) = 
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "spotify", "Spotify"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "Spotify"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Spotify"
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
XdndProxy(WINDOW): window id # 0x1a00002
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        program specified location: 0, 0
        window gravity: Static
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 27058
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "it_IT.UTF-8"
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "placobravo"
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, _NET_WM_PING
```

At startup both firefox and spotify loads, but only firefox gets placed in its right workspace, and I really can't get what's going on since I'm using the exactly same syntax. I already tried using a different workspace but it doesn't work.

---

After a bit more of searching I've found a solution in another post

> https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/2060

Comment: You could try using `[instance="spotify"]` instead. It might be that the class name "Spotify" does not get assigned until after the window was already created.

Comment: This didnt work, but I found a solution. I've updated the post

Comment: This behavior is documented exactly on the docs now. And the question has been answered (though improperly in the question itself)

Comment: Which is at: https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#assign_workspace: Another known issue is with Spotify, which doesn’t set the class hints when mapping the window, meaning you’ll have to use a for_window rule to assign Spotify to a specific workspace.

Answer (score 20):

(Taken exactly from question). Simply use

```
for_window [class="Spotify"] move to workspace $ws4
```

This is also in the [Arch i3 Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/i3#Default_workspace_for_Spotify)

Comment: this works, but assign keyword doesn't. it has different functionality thou

Comment: 2020 and this still seems to be the correct solution to the ever lasting issue...

Comment: Half of 2021 gone yet it's still an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, I use `xwininfo` to get window id and insert it into

```
assign [class="<Window ID"] $ws<number>
```

Which also works for Spotify. However, as there is a free and premium version of Spotify it generalises to the i3 config setting:

```
assign [class="^Spotify*"] $ws<number>
```

In the config file